# Netsuite Script - Update Custom quantity available field // location = warehouse

Tags: javascript, scripting, netsuite, inventory

I am trying create a script so that it can update custom field with quantity available from "warehouse" location(we have multiple location). First i was trying to set value in the custom field but its not working.
Code:

```
{
var stdField = 'custitem_annaslinenssku'; // Custom field for quantity
var qtyAvail = 0;
qtyAvail = rec.getValue('locationquantityavailable');
}

function Qtyupdate()
{   
if(location == 1)
nlapiSetFieldValue(stdField,qtyAvail);
return true;
}
```

Then i wanted to add a logic like "if the quantity is less than 12 then script should make those item quantity 0.

I also wanted to add quantity available for kit/package item but totally no idea.

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello Tony, I was trying to copy the quantity available and enter it on the custom field i created on item. after that i wanted to add logic to that code "if the quantity is less than 12 then script should make those item quantity = 0.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to share how you are using the information. It looks like you might be trying to set up an inventory reserve. You might be better off to create a reserve location and transfer inventory there. Then you can put your 12 items into the reserve location and make that not available for website.

If that's not what you are tying to accomplish you might want to look at Netsuite's inventory management fields.

However to answer your question you can't normally get the inventory location fields from the item record so in a scheduled script you'd be doing something like the following. If you are running this from a user script beware of governance issues:

```
 var items = nlapiSearchRecord('inventoryitem', null, 
    [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('inventorylocation', null, 'is', 1), // your target inventory location internal id.
        new nlobjSearchFilter('isinactive', null, 'is', 'F'),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('locationavailable', null, 'lessthan', 13),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('custitem_my_custom_field', null, 'greaterthan', 0)
    ],[
        new nlobjSearchColumn('locationavailable'),
        new nlobjSearchColumn('custitem_my_custom_field')
    ]);
if(!items) return;
items.forEach(function(it){
    var customLevel = parseInt(it.getValue('locationavailable'), 10)||0;
    customLevel = Math.min(customLevel - 12, 0);
    if(customLevel == parseInt(it.getValue('custitem_my_custom_field'), 10)) return;
    nlapiSubmitField(it.getRecordType(), it.getId(), 'custitem_my_custom_field', customLevel);
});
```

Comment: Reserving inventory seems to be such a common process and request that we get. Really wish it didn't require custom implementation.